# django query using IN()

Tags: django, django-models

I have problem with model built like this:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    cook = models.ForeignKey(Cook)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

I'm trying to select **all toppings** used by provided **cook** on his pizzas.

on SQL I could use `select * from Toppings t where t.id IN(select topping_id from Pizzas where cook_id = ?)` or some other way (surely more efficient :P ). Problem is I'm bound to use django models, because of underlying dependencies, like paging.

Because it's database used by many applications it would be great if it could be done without changing models...

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but might help you in your work, you can also find all reverse links in many to many for a particular object e.g. some_topping.pizza_set.all() gives all pizza-s that use that topic, just make sure isinstance(some_topping, Topping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Topping.objects.filter(pizza__cook=mycook)
```

Comment: Is that a feature introduced in django 1.4 or has it always been around? going backwards through relationships?

Comment: @dm03514 it's been around for a very long time. At least 1.0 I think.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton longer than that, I've been using Django since 0.91 and it was well-established even then.

Comment: Wow, I never expected this to be so easy :D Thank you :)